# C++ Call an abstract class method using member function pointer

Tags: c++11

I have an abstract class:

```
class Proto{
public:
  virtual void fu() = 0;
};
```

Then I have a class that implements `fu`:

```
class Impl: public Proto{
public:
    void fu();
};

void Impl::fu(){
    printf("im fu");
}
```

And I have another class that needs to use `fu` implementation without knowing implementation itself:

```
class Invoke{
public:
    void useFu(void (Proto::*)());
};
```

Then I call `useFu`:

```
inv.useFu(static_cast<void (Proto::*)()>(&Impl::fu));
```

**So my question is, how I call `fu()` in `useFu(void (Proto::*)())`?**

```
void Invoke::useFu(void (Proto::*fu)()){
   fu() <--- how to use it?
};
```

I can`t call an abstract class method directly so I created some kind of pre-implementation:

```
class PreImpl: public Proto{
public:
    virtual void fu();
};

void PreImpl::fu()
{
    printf("I'm the wrong fu");
}
```

Then in `useFu` i call `fu()`:

```
void Invoke::useFu(void (Proto::*fu)()){
    PreImpl preImpl;
    (static_cast<PreImpl>(preImpl).*fu)();
};
```

But after call of `useFu` i got a wrong function being executed:

```
void main(){
Invoke inv;

inv.useFu(static_cast<void (Proto::*)()>(&Impl::fu));
}
```

Prints out:

```
I'm the wrong fu
```

Comment: In order to call `fu` - or generally, any non-static member function - you need an instance of an object on which to call it. Somewhere in your program, an instance of `Impl` needs to be created, and made available to `Invoke::useFu` in some way. A pointer-to-member is useless on its own, without an object to obtain that member from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an XY problem actually.

As [Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) suggested I end up just passing a class as a function parameter.

```
void Invoke::useFu(Proto* impl){
 impl->fu();
};

inv.useFu(&Impl);
```